# Test pixels in image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to denoise an image by averaging all pixels that are within a certain euclidian distance using the following loop. Currently this loop takes 65 seconds and likely needs performed thousands of times. Is there a way to accomplish this in python without a prohibitive run time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for row in range(0, width):
    for column in range(0, height):
        if euclid_dist(point, pix[row,column]) <= threshold:
            to_average[(row,column)] = pix[row, column]
```

euclid_dist is defined as the following:

```
def euclid_dist(tuple1, tuple2):

    tot_sq = 0
    for num1, num2 in zip(tuple1, tuple2):
    tot_sq += (num1 + num2)**2
    return math.sqrt(tot_sq)
```

Comment: Convolve the image with a circular mask the size you want.

Comment: Could you provide a little more information? I think I know what you're getting at, but I'm not sure how I'd code it

Comment: NickT appears to have you covered. So I will just comment. 1) zip might be overkill. Try using an index based loop 2) when there is a lot of numbers to compute Numpy is the usual answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just average everything in a circle (equally, rather than with a gaussian), you can make a hard circle kernel, then convolve your image with it as below.

```
# make a noisy circle thing
img = np.random.randint(100, 200, (200, 200), dtype=np.uint8)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-100, 100), np.arange(-100, 100))
img = img + 10 * (xx**2 + yy**2 < 50**2)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

```
# make a non-standard kernel
radius = 10
kernel_size = 2 * int(radius) + 1 # odd
xy = np.arange(-kernel_size//2 + 1, kernel_size//2 + 1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xy, xy)

kernel = np.zeros((kernel_size,) * 2)
kernel[xx**2 + yy**2 <= radius**2] = 1
plt.imshow(kernel)
```

[image]

```
# convolve the two, depending on the mode, it will change the dimensions of the output
plt.imshow(sig.convolve2d(img, kernel, mode='valid'))
```

[image]

If you want to de-noise, you could also use a gaussian kernel, which is a bit more common. It's more simply called "Gaussian blurring" then.